# In galleryview image and a text

Tags: android, galleryview

In my application I am using galleryview to display to display images..In that my requirement is that i have to display the image and right to that image i have to display a text..I done everything and it is working fine..But my problem is that "SPACE" is coming in between between the images...

Actually i want output like this:

```
----         ----      ----- 
img1 Text   img2 TExt  img3  text
----        -----      ----
```

But i am getting output like this:

```
----                       ----                                   ----- 
img1 Text                  img2 TExt                             img3  text
----                       -----                                    ----
```

My layout file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    



       <RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"          
         />

        <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/homesectiongallery"        
        android:textColor="#CCCCCC"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

      />

   </RelativeLayout>
  <View android:background="#B3B3B3" android:layout_width = "fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dip" android:layout_marginTop="5px"/>




</LinearLayout>
```

My gallery holding Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Gallery 
    android:id="@+id/Gallerysection" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Gallery>


      <ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    


</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me to solve this..Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why do you have a <View> at the bottom of your layout?

Comment: Can you post your layout code which holds galleryView

Comment: Thanks Andro Selva..I have to draw a line below that galleryview..Thats y i have a view..

Comment: Thanks  rajpara..I will post my gallery code..

Comment: Two suggestion, 1. make wrap content to relative layout in My layout file, 2. set android:spacing="5dp" in Gallery then check

Comment: Please make <View android:layout_width = "fill_parent" to match parent

Comment: Thanks rajpara ..I tried ur 2 suggestions..Now there is the view is coming as cutted line..I want a straight horizontal line..But it is coming like this.. -------- -------- ------- -------- -------......But i need ------------------------------------.....